# Visual Studio "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file" on a library that is not used or include

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have `UnitTest` project than use my own `NeuralNetwork` library project that use my own `Boost` project (I rebuild boost with a `Boost.vcxproj`) and `UnitTest` don't use Boost. So, why my `UnitTest` project try to link `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib` ?

I check, I have no boost reference in my `UnitTests.vcxproj` except the folder to include .hpp files.
My `Boost` project and `NeuralNetwork` project build without any error and correctly gerenate a Boost.lib and NeuralNetwork.lib.

*error message*

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: UnitTests, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Building Custom Rule C:/Programming/Github/NeuralNetwork/tests/unit_tests/CMakeLists.txt
1>cl : command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-g'
1>ExamplesTest.cpp
1>SaveNeuralNetworkTest.cpp
1>UnitTestTests.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib'
1>Done building project "UnitTests.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

*Global CMakeLists.txt*

```
project(NeuralNetwork CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")


add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

*NeuralNetwork CMakeLists.txt*

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)

include_directories(external_library/boost_1_71_0_minimal)
add_subdirectory(external_library/boost_1_71_0_minimal/libs/serialization)

add_library(NeuralNetwork ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(NeuralNetwork Boost)
```

*Test CMakeLists.txt*

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)

add_subdirectory(googletest-release-1.10.0)

include_directories(../src src)
include_directories(../src/external_library/boost_1_71_0_minimal)

add_library(GTestExtended ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(GTestExtended gtest)

add_subdirectory(unit_tests)
add_subdirectory(dataset_tests)
```

Comment: Please add CMakeLists.txt into your question.

Comment: @chwala Done, but my code compiles and works when I run it on Linux with the following command : `cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./.. && make && ./unit_tests/UnitTests.out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a command to ignore the library to main `CMakeLists.txt` and it's works perfectly.

Code added to *CMakeLists.txt*

```
if(MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /NODEFAULTLIB:\"libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib\"")
endif()
```